# facebook comments - doesn't let me moderate

Tags: javascript, facebook, drupal, facebook-comments

I'm trying to install facebook comments on my page, but it doesn't let me moderate. On a test page with only the comments plugin - no problem. the same code exactly on a live page - doesn't let me moderate.

the test page:
http://www.radicalislam.org/test3.html

the live page:
http://www.radicalislam.org/news/pakistan-hands-huge-prison-sentence-bin-laden-informant

tried to debug, it shows the right admin and app id.

it's a drupal site, if it's important

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you are using partial URLs for the href. Use the full one.

Use the following instead.

`<div class="fb-comments" href="http://www.radicalislam.org/news/pakistan-hands-huge-prison-sentence-bin-laden-informant" data-num-posts="5" data-width="580"></div>`

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately my work Firewall wouldn't let me click through to the link.

Are you using the correct URL when you add the Facebook comments to the page? If you aren't you won't be able to moderate, you will likely need to dynamically add the URL to the generated code.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried scraping the page using the debug tool (as the admin)?
http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.radicalislam.org%2Ftest3.html

This will read the updated admin IDs and let the administrator see the moderation panel in the plugin and via https://developers.facebook.com/tools/comments